# Kotlin unable to pass get request parameters (Fuel library)

Tags: kotlin, fuel

For this simple example taken straight from the [docs](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/blob/master/fuel/README.md):

```
Fuel.get("https://httpbin.org/get", listOf("foo" to "foo", "bar" to "bar"))
    .also { println(it.url) }
```

This prints out `https://httpbin.org/get`, as opposed to `https://httpbin.org/get?foo=foo&bar=bar`

How do I fix this? I'm using `fuel 2.1.0`

Comment: from the docs, that is expected behaviour ? `Fuel.post("https://httpbin.org/post", listOf("foo" to "foo", "bar" to "bar"))
    .also { println(it.url) }` this prints : `https://httpbin.org/post`

Comment: No, I'm talking about a `get` request.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a representation of Fuel `Request`. It doesn't construct the full url instantly. The parameters are fine. You can check the response for example:

```
val (request, response, result) = Fuel.get(
    "https://httpbin.org/get", listOf("foo" to "foo", "bar" to "bar")
).response()
println(response.url) // prints https://httpbin.org/get?foo=foo&bar=bar
```

Comment: why it contradicts the documentation?